# how to block ip address for 24 hours in LINUX Using iptables

Tags: linux, unix, iptables, devops

How can I **block** ip address for 24 hours if in 1 second it hits is more than `100` using `iptables`.?

Answer (score 0):

`iptables` does not have the concept of expiration dates.

You would need a program like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) which runs as a daemon and remembers to remove entries that it creates.